# Transforming between a local and global frame for a Kalman filter

Tags: kinematics, kalman-filter

I want to track an object in a global Cartesian frame, denoted $G$. The object has a local frame, denoted $L$. The object is controlled by a velocity command $v$, defined in its local frame. This "world" is a 2D space as below:

[image]

In this world, the object can only translate (no rotation), and the local axes and global axes are aligned. Therefore, I can track the object using a regular Kalman filter.

I define the state as $x_t = \begin{bmatrix}x_t\\y_t\end{bmatrix}$ where $x$ and $y$ are the positions in the global frame. The control velocity is defined as $v_t = \begin{bmatrix}a_t\\b_t\end{bmatrix}$, where $a$ and $b$ are the local velocities defined in the local frame. The state transition matrix is defined as $A = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and the input matrix is defined as $B = \begin{bmatrix}\Delta t&0\\0&\Delta t\end{bmatrix}$, where $\Delta t$ is the time step.

So overall, my prediction stage of the Kalman filter is:

$\begin{bmatrix}x_{t+1}\\y_{t+1}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_t\\y_t\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}\Delta t&0\\0&\Delta t\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a_t\\b_t\end{bmatrix}$

---

But now I want to allow the object to rotate, about the axis going into the screen. So, my "world" now looks like this:

[image]

And now, the axes of the two frames are not aligned, so I cannot use the state transition model I defined above. So, to account for this in the Kalman filter, I do the following.

I take the current estimate of the object's pose, and create a transformation matrix to represent this frame. Let us denote this $T_{GL}$, which transforms a vector from the object's local frame to the global frame. Then, I take the velocity vector $v_L$, which is currently defined in the local frame, and transform to the global frame as follows: $v_G = T_{GL} v_L$.

Once this is done, I have the control velocity defined in the global frame, instead of the local frame. And so then I just use this velocity in the Kalman filter defined in the first example above. My intuition is that once the velocity is transformed to the global frame, I can use the simple state transformation model defined above, because the axes of the velocity and the global frame are now aligned.

But I am rather confused now. It seems like I have effectively implemented the Extended Kalman Filter (EKF), because the relationship between the local velocity and the state update is actually non-linear, due to the rotation. The EKF involves linearising around the current estimate, and I am effectively doing this by computing the transformation matrix for the current estimation of the object's pose. However, when I read about the EKF, the maths is much more complex. It involves Taylor series expansions and partial derivatives, whereas all I am doing is transforming a vector from the estimated local frame to the global frame.

Have I actually implemented an EKF, unknowingly? Or is there something about my implementation that is fundamentally wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not accidentally implemented an Extended Kalman filter. All you are essentially doing is preprocessing the data with a known quantity $T_{GL}$ into your global frame. You therefore removed any indication of rotation and therefore your math is still happening in the global frame which allows you to continue to use your Kalman filter implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, $T_{GL}$ is not known; it is derived from my current estimate of the state. The state contains the Cartesian position and Euler rotation, and $T_{GL}$ is then a matrix representation of this. But what I am most confused about is why we even need the EKF when we can just do a coordinate transform in this way. This post (https://tinyurl.com/vk5nsel) says that you cannot do a transformation from Polar to Cartesian coordinates, since the mapping is non-linear, and therefore you need to use the EKF. Isn't this the same in my case, since rotations are involved?

Comment: Ahh ok. Yes you will now need an EKF. The reason you need an EKF is that you can no longer express your state transition matrices as a linear update(matrix math) as $T_{GL}$ is going to be composed of cos, and sin. Given the state $[x,y,\theta]$ try to rewrite your prediction step with matrices. You will find that you can't do it.

Comment: I understand that $T_{GL}$ is composed of cos and sin in general, and so in general the prediction step is a non-linear function. However, what I am doing is taking the current state estimate, and then calculating $T_{GL}$ at this particular point. Then, $T_{GL}$ is just a matrix of numbers. So I can use it to transform a velocity from the local frame to the global frame, and hence use this velocity to update the state in the global frame. Would this be ok?

Comment: But in order to compute $T_{GL}$ at this point you also need to estimate the $\theta$ which you said is not known. If you can get $T_{GL}$ from some external source then it is probably not kosher, but you could probably continue to use just a Kalman filter. It just won't properly fuse the uncertainty.

Comment: That is true; $\theta$ is unknown. But I am taking the current estimate of $\theta$ (as well as the current estimate of $x$ and $y$), and using these to create $T_{GL}$. And then I use this to transform everything from the local frame into the global frame. As such, my measurements and dynamics are in the same frame as the state vector, so it all becomes very simple and linear, and I can use a regular Kalman filter, rather than an EKF. At least, this is my understanding...

Comment: I am reading a paper ("On polar and versus Cartesian coordinates for target tracking"), which says: "The non-linearity of measurements can be handled either by the use of the extended Kalman filter or by converting the measurements to Cartesian coordinates prior to filtering. This second approach, if carried out
properly (conversion is debiased and consistent), is exactand therefore preferred." So this suggests that directly converting from one frame (e.g. my local frame) to another (e.g. my global frame) is not only valid, but actually desired. Am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: Ok that paper makes sense. However, they are just converting a polar measurement into the cartesian plane, which is not applicable in your case. They don't have the concept of a local frame as you do. Everything is happening in the global frame. You can't do this as you also care about the rotation between the local frame and the global frame as that is what allows you to convert the velocity.


Essentially this paper is non applicable to your case.

Comment: As soon as you say the words "estimate of $\theta$" then it means you need to have it in your state vector. And once you have that it means you need an EKF. If you notice in the paper you mentioned their state is just global pos and velocity. Which works for just 3D position tracking.

Comment: Reading this paper I am even more sure. You have to 2 choices. Use some external source that gives you $T_{GL}$ and that way continue to use your Kalman filter, or estimate it and therefore use an EKF.

Comment: OK thanks. So with the case in the paper, I understand that the state is all defined in one frame, so there is no need to convert from a local velocity to a global velocity, like in my case. But with the case in the paper, wouldn't the measurement noise model need to also be defined in the cartesian frame? Otherwise, transforming this noise from the polar to cartesian frame is non-linear, and therefore this would invalidate the update of the Gaussian state uncertainty,

Comment: He explicitly takes care of that with the "Debiasing of the measurements".

Answer (score 0):

but about the local frame to global frame conversion what is the reference value of global frame how to set the values. if we are implementing the kalman filter that use cases is to reduce the noises the predicting the next value then how i can implement this concept for mobile phone ?

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Please create your own new question if you have one. You may include a url to this question if it provides useful context for us to understand your question.